# NSInputStream read:maxBytes always returns 0

Tags: nsinputstream

I'm baffled. I have an open NSInputStream which thinks it has bytes available.  When I read the bytes, the operation always returns 0.  I've searched everywhere and my code looks like most everyone else's doing the same thing.  This is such a low level operation that I can't figure out how it could go wrong.
I've tried this by connecting to a number of different hosts.  I've also watched with Wireshark and I can see the host receiving the bytes I write, but the read:maxBytes operation still always returns 0???

```
case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    {
        //Check stream status
        NSString *returnedStatus;
        commandLength = [commandString length];
        [commandString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, commandLength)];
        returnedStatus = [NSString stringWithString:[self decodeStatus:[stream streamStatus]]];
        [commandString appendFormat:@"inputStream %@ status=%@\n",stream, returnedStatus];
        [self writeCommand:commandString];


        uint8_t *buf[buffLength];
        NSUInteger len = 0;

        len = [(NSInputStream *)stream read:(uint8_t *)buf maxLength:buffLength];

        if (len == 0) {
            //len = buffLength;
            [self writeCommand:@"No bytes read!\n"];
        }
```

Comment: Hi, Any luck, i am also facing the same problem...

Answer (score 5):

I also run into this issue and i found an answer in the documentation:

```
- (BOOL)hasBytesAvailable
```

Return Value:

YES if the receiver has bytes available to read, otherwise NO. **May also return YES if a read must be attempted in order to determine the availability of bytes.**